# Several associations between one pair of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I learned basic associations. If there are two models "Book" and "Person", I can associate Person with books which he wrote, and use syntax like "John.books". However, if I want to associate these models in different way, for example, associating Person with his favorite books, how do I this? "John.books" is already used with other meanings.

I want to do something like "John.writings", "John.favorite_books".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So far I understand your question is you want to name those association in different way? right? If so then I have your answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to name associations.

Comment: okey, I just finished writing your answer. check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your person class:

```
# person.rb
 has_many :writings, class_name: 'Book'
 has_many :favorite_books, class_name: 'Book'

 # if you want to put some condition on your association,
 # has_many :writings, -> { where( some_key: 'some_value') }, class_name: 'Book'  
 # has_many :favorite_books, -> { where( favorite: true ) }, class_name: 'Book'
```